# How to use kotlin coroutines in firebase database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to access chatting room Using firestore and coroutines.

```
    fun getOwner() {
        runBlocking {
            var de = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                firestore.collection("Chat").document("cF7DrENgQ4noWjr3SxKX").get()
            }
            var result = de.await().result
        }
```

But i get error like this :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
    Process: com.example.map_fetchuser_trest, PID: 19329
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source:121)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.example.map_fetchuser_trest.model.Repository$getOwner$1.invokeSuspend(Repository.kt:53)
```

How can i get chat document? when i use origin api like below, I can access chat room document.

```
        firestore.collection("Chat").document(
            "cF7DrENgQ4noWjr3SxKX"
        ).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val chatDTO = task.result?.toObject(Appointment::class.java)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Task` is the thing one awaits on, but you wrapped it in another layer of `async`. Remove the `async`:

```
fun getOwner() {
    runBlocking {
        var de =  firestore.collection("Chat").document("cF7DrENgQ4noWjr3SxKX").get()
        var result = de.await().result
    }
}
```

However, by using `runBlocking()` you have shot yourself in the foot and wrote blocking code that just formally uses an async API to no good effect.

To truly benefit from it, you must have a

```
suspend fun getOwner() = firestore
     .collection("Chat")
     .document("cF7DrENgQ4noWjr3SxKX")
     .get()
     .await()
     .result
```

and `launch` a coroutine at the place you call it from:

```
launch {
    val owner = getOwner()
    // update the GUI
}
```

This assumes you're calling `launch` from an object that is a `CoroutineScope`.

Comment: If i remove "async", where ".await()" function in suspend func does come from?

Comment: You need `Task.await()` which is defined in [org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services).

Comment: It's not possible to use the same concept (of suspend function in coroutines) and also have firestore real-time functionality, right? I ask this because the code showed on the answer is a good example of how you can avoid the problem of "callback hell" (a call inside another call's callback) in a scenario where you we have to query a collection multiple times and merge the results because of firestore queries limitations. But, once again, is there a way to do while still having the real-time functionality? Or, is there a way to make multiple calls without having the problem of callback hell?

Comment: Could someone tell me in which dispatcher the `await()` function gets called? Is there any performance difference in calling .await() between the `Dispatchers.IO` and `Dispatchers.Main`

Comment: @Andrew `await()` behaves just like any other suspendable function and gets executed in the current dispatcher. Where it gets executed has nothing to do with where the code that runs the task itself is executed. Just as its name says, it does nothing but wait. You should therefore let it use the `Main` dispatcher.

Comment: `await()` returns query snapshot, what usually returned in `addOnCompleteListener()`, where are the exceptions handling?

Comment: @PavelPoley `await()` throws the exception.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik so it should be wrapped in try/catch block then

Comment: @PavelPoley It may or may not be wrapped in try-catch, just like any other exception-throwing code. Exception handling can happen at any level, which is another advantage of this approach.

Answer (score 7):

```
 val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
override suspend fun saveBinToDB(bin: Bin): Result<Unit> {
    lateinit var result:Result<Unit>
    db.collection("bins")
        .add(bin)
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
            result = Result.Success(Unit)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e)
            result = Result.Error(Exception())
        }
        .await()
    return result
}

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.7"
```

Comment: Dang, this is what I was looking for. There are so many examples regarding interacting with Firestore using Kotlin, and most, if not all of them, use that `await()` function. The implementation of that jetbrains library is the one you need.

Answer (score 3):

The usage of `runBlocking{..}` in the first code snippet works as follows: the `runBlocking` function *blocks* to execute the parameter lambda code (and the lambda code will suspend inside). It gives less sense.

You may want to start a coroutine with `launch{..}` function instead and use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main){..}` to have the block executed in the UI thread, e.g. to show the fetched results. You may also implement `CoroutineScope` in your activity class.

The first step - you need to turn the Firebase API call into a suspending function. It could be done with `suspendCoroutine{..}` function (there are several more functions like `suspendCancellableCoroutine{..}` in the kotlinx.coroutines library.

There is an integration library with Google Play Services that provides support for Firebase
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to get `await()` function. Check your `build.gradle` should have below dependencies -

```
def coroutines = '1.6.4'
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines"
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$coroutines"
```

Now instead of Complete/Failure Listener, use `await()` just like used in @Marko answer -

```
suspend fun getDataFromFireStore() = firestore
                                        .collection("some key")
                                        .document("some key")
                                        .get()
                                        .await()
                                        .documents
```