# Is it possible to return Firestore data from a function?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In [this code snippet](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects), data gets retrieved from Firestore:

```
val docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ")
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
    val city = documentSnapshot.toObject<City>()
}
```

How could I turn this into a function, that returns a city object? Something like this:

```
fun getCity(): City?{
   val docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ")
   docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
       val city = documentSnapshot.toObject<City>()
       return city
}
```

Can I somehow 'await' the result when I call the *getCity()* function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one important thing you'll need to know:

All Firestore APIs are asynchronous. They return immediately, and you must use the callback to get the results.  There is no guarantee when the callback will be invoked, and it must be handled asynchronously.  *Your `getCity()` function will not be able to return an object immediately.*

`get()` returns a Task object (provided by the [Play services Task API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks)) that represents the asynchronous query.  If you want to `await()` the result of that, your easiest route is to use the [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/) library to convert that task into a `suspend fun` that can be awaited.  If you do this, your `getCity()` should also be a `suspend fun` so that it can deliver the result asynchronously to its caller.

See also: [How to use kotlin coroutines in firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204428/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-in-firebase-database)