# Can't reassign variable with data from Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to reassign my `var shopModel` with data that I fetch from Firestore. I am fetching a document from Firestore and casting said data to a custom object - this works, but `var shopModel` never gets reassigned. I am clearly missing something, and appreciate if someone could help me out.

**ShopStore.kt**

```
   override fun getSingle(documentPath: String): ShopModel {
        var shopModel = ShopModel()
        firestore.firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().build()
        val document = firestore.collection("shops").document(documentPath)
        document.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            shopModel = it.toObject(ShopModel::class.java)!!
            return@addOnSuccessListener
        }
            .addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                info("get failed with ", exception)
                return@addOnFailureListener
            }
        return shopModel
    }
```

**ShopModel.kt**

```
@Parcelize
data class ShopModel (
    var uuid: String?,
    var name: String?
) : Parcelable {constructor() : this("","")}
```

---

***Edit:***
I changed up the code to make use of coroutines but I still face the same issue - the variable does not get reassigned.

**ShopStore.kt** with coroutines

```
    override fun getSingle(documentPath: String): ShopModel {
        var shopModel = ShopModel()
        firestore.firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().build()
        val document = firestore.collection("shops").document(documentPath)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            shopModel = document.get().await().toObject(shopModel::class.java)!!
            
        }
        return shopModel
    }
```

Comment: get() is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the query is complete.  The callbacks are invoked some time later, after getSingle returns.  You should use a LiveData or coroutines to manage the asynchronous flow of code here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look into that!

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried adding coroutines but I still face the same issue as before. I updated my answer with the changes I made. Have I implemented coroutines wrongly, or is there something else causing the issues?

Comment: Ye, it looks like your coroutine is not implemented correctly. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55205027/12232507) for insights.