# How can I wait for a response from the database (Firestore) so that my code can continue to be executed?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how I can wait for a data read in the database to be completed or for an update to be completed to continue with my code

```
db.collection("markers").document(markerID).update(
                    mapOf(
                        "titulo" to title,
                        "descripcion" to description
                    )
                ).addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!")
                }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error updating document", e)
                        error = 1
                    }

        if (error == 1){
            Toast.makeText(this.requireContext(), "No tiene permisos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this.requireContext(), "Cambio realizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                  }
```

For example, in this code, the if block is executed without waiting for the change to the database to complete and therefore the error variable never changes.

Comment: Any code that needs to handle errors, needs to be inside the onFailure method, or be called from there. There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 1):

Put if block in `.addOnSuccessListener` should solve this, Or you can use alternative: [How to use kotlin coroutines in firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204428/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-in-firebase-database)